# Replace commas between only same starting letter strings

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace commas between only same starting letter strings?

Here is what I have, partially working:

```js
const regexA = /(A.+?)(, )(A)/g;
const regexB = /(B.+?)(, )(B)/g;

let value = "A1C, A2, A3B, A4, B1, B2A, B3".replace(regexA, '$1/$3');
value = value.replace(regexB, '$1/$3');
console.log(value); //prints A1C/A2, A3B/A4, B1/B2A, B3
```

**Goal: A1C/A2/A3B/A4, B1/B2A/B3**

Comment: Use `value.replace(/\b([A-Z])\w+(?:,\s*\1\w+)+/g, (x) => x.replace(/,\s*/g, '/'))` or `value.replace(/\b(([A-Z])\w+),\s*(?=\2)/g, '$1/')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const regexA = /((.)[^,]+), (?=\2|$)/g;

let value = "A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3".replace(regexA, '$1/');
console.log(value);
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Nua1Ot/1)

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question a bit but this covers all my cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [positive lookahead assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve the result where you can assert by capturing the first character.

```js
const regexA = /((.)[^,]+), (?=\2)/ig;

let value = "A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3".replace(regexA, '$1/');
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question because it is not always letter digit comma.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a group for the letter and relace only if the same group is found later.

```js
let value = "A1b, A2d, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3".replace(/([a-z])([^,]+),\s+(?=\1)/gi, '$1$2/');

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question because it is not always letter digit comma.

Answer (score 0):

1. Updated the expression to match the trailing `,`
2. Added trailing slash in `.replace()`
3. Finally replaced `/,` with `,` to take care of extra trailing slash

```js
const regexA = /(A.)(, )(A.)(, )/g;
const regexB = /(B.)(, )(B.)(, )/g;

let value = "A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3".replace(regexA, '$1/$3/');

value = value.replace(regexB, ", $1/$3/");

console.log(value.replace(/\/, /g, ', ')); //prints A1/A2/A3/A4, B1/B2/B3
```

Comment: Try it with `A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2`

Comment: @Toto hmm it does not work. I think we already have the answer for this. Anyways, thanks for letting me know.